# How can I access a field value from a sub collection in Firebase with Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Sorry but I asked wrong. Can yo guys delete, please! Sorry!!!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your method that you call to convert you are not calling again the documents from the collection.

```
List mapToList({DocumentSnapshot doc, List<DocumentSnapshot> docList}) {
    if (docList != null) {
      List<Store> storeList = [];
      docList.forEach((document) {
        //I WANT TO GET A FIELD IN THIS SUBCOLLECTION!!!
        String productName = document.reference.collection("products"); 
  //this does not give you the data but just a collection reference. 
}
}
```

You need to do something like this again

```
CollectionReference productsRef = document.reference.collection('products');
 List<DocumentSnapshot> productsnap = productsRef.getDocuments().documents;

productsnap.forEach((data){ data[StringConstant.productName] });
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping... But in List<DocumentSnapshot> productsSnap, I am having the following error: "The getter "documents" isn't defined for the class Future<QuerySnapshot>

I am using BLOC, if it helps. Help me man, please.

Comment: Sure, will try to do best. My bad the getDocuments() returns a future. so you can await for it 
QuerySnapshot productsnap = await productsRef.getDocuments();
List<DocumentSnapshot> = productsnap.documents;

Comment: It looks like is working, it catches the name, but because of the await and async, it doesn't built the Listview. I think its something with my StreamBuilder. Thanks anyway. I will study the documentation and try to understand better. Thanks man!

Comment: Can you help me to built this function mapToList with Future???? Please!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you to want skip 'stores' collection and jump to 'products' collection.

You can do it using collectionGroup.

**Updated**

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('products').snapshots().listen((data) {
      data.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
        if(change.document.data['category']=='banana')
        print('store name: ${change.document.reference.parent().parent().documentID}');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Hey my friend! Thanks for your answer... What I want is to built a Firebase Search System where I can search for a Product and built in ListView.builder the Stores that have the selected product.